# Translation of a query string to python dictionary for requests.post

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to make a login in a web page with requests. It's a post request so I'm using a dictionary to introduce the parameters. However, the query string to translate is quite weird and I'm not getting any success passing it to a dict. The query to translate looks as follow:

```
 userid=...&password=...&submit=*Iniciar+sesi%C3%B3n&title=
```

The part of the query which is causing to me some troubles is

```
  submit=*Iniciar+sesi%C3%B3n
```

I don't know how to turn it correctly to the dictionary to be well interpreted by the request.

Comment: It might be a unicode problem, since `%C3%B3` is the representation of `ó` in unicode.

Comment: `parse_qs('submit=*Iniciar+sesi%C3%B3n')` (I assume you're using [`urlparse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs)) gives me `{'submit': ['*Iniciar sesi\xc3\xb3n']}`.  What do you want to get instead?

Comment: I suppose this is the result I was expecting. With that value, the query is well made, isn't it? I'm using it now in my code but I continue having a problem with the final result, so I guess I continue having other problem in the code...
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This isn't a full answer but I can't comment due to reputation.*

I'm not sure how `*Iniciar+sesi%C3%B3n` ought to be parsed, but you can use `cgi.parse_qs` or `urllib.parse.parse_qs` to parse the query string into a dict. This will result in a `'submit': ['*Iniciar sesi\xc3\xb3n']` entry. In order to get around this, you could write code to explicitly parse the value of the `submit` into something that your code can use later on.